# Text that is centered horizontally but absolutely placed vertically

Tags: positioning

I want to be able to position a chunk of text (which could be anything, could have `\includegraphics`, and could be on multiple lines) at the center of a page horizontally. However, I want to be able to customize its vertical position, say 4 inches from the top.

This chunk should be independent of the document's normal contents. So it should affect anything else on the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried with `\vspace{}`?

Comment: @Thanos That would mess up the rest of the document, I guess?

Comment: I would think placing it with something like [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos), [`background`](http://ctan.org/pkg/background), [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) or [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz) would be necessary to place stuff on the page and not affect everything else.

Comment: Actually I am not so sure about what are you trying to do. The `\vspace{}` command creates a vertical space on the exact position(and only) you'd like. Try it and see if it will ruin the rest of the document.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent"? Should it *not* clash with anything else or should it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1in} % sets our horizontal unit of measuring
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1in} % sets our vertical unit of measuring
    \textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm} % and we start measuring in the top left corner

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry} % I'm assuming you're using letter paper if you use inches

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for filler text

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{8.5}(0,4)\centering
  % 8.5 = width of the block
  % 0 = zero horizontal units away from our origin
  % 4 = four vertical units away from our origin
\fbox{\Huge\textsc{Hello World}}
  % the \fbox isn't necessary -- you can put here whatever you want.
\end{textblock}

\lipsum[1-4] % to provoke the clash

\end{document}
```

[image: output]